# EXPLAIN type "all". Not using index on inner join for no reason

Tags: mysql

I'm running a query like the one below (where '70' is an example, cause I use the same query in my PHP code only changing that value for every "clasificacion") and I wanted to optimize it, so I used EXPLAIN:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT TE.PK_ID_TAREA_EMPRESA AS ID_EMPRESA, TE.NOMBRE AS NOMBRE_EMPRESA, TCA.PK_ID_TAREA_CATEGORIA AS ID_CATEGORIA, TCA.NOMBRE AS NOMBRE_CATEGORIA, T.TIPO AS TIPO, T.CLIENTE AS CLIENTE, T.PETICION AS PETICION, T.FACTURABLE AS FACTURABLE, TCOM.COMENTARIO AS COMENTARIO, TCOM.PENDIENTE AS PENDIENTE FROM TAREA_COMENTARIO TCOM
    INNER JOIN TAREA T
    ON TCOM.TAREA_TIPO = T.TIPO
    AND TCOM.TAREA_CLIENTE = T.CLIENTE
    AND TCOM.TAREA_PETICION = T.PETICION
    INNER JOIN TAREA_EMPRESA_ TE
    ON TCOM.FK_ID_TAREA_EMPRESA = TE.PK_ID_TAREA_EMPRESA
    INNER JOIN TAREA_CATEGORIA_ TCA
    ON TCOM.FK_ID_TAREA_CATEGORIA = TCA.PK_ID_TAREA_CATEGORIA
    INNER JOIN TAREA_CLASIFICACION_ TCL
    ON TCOM.FK_ID_TAREA_CLASIFICACION = TCL.PK_ID_TAREA_CLASIFICACION
    WHERE TCOM.FK_ID_TAREA_CLASIFICACION = 70
GROUP BY TCOM.FK_ID_TAREA_EMPRESA, TCOM.FK_ID_TAREA_CATEGORIA, TCOM.FK_ID_TAREA_CLASIFICACION, TCOM.TAREA_TIPO, TCOM.TAREA_CLIENTE, TCOM.TAREA_PETICION;
```

EXPLAIN returns me this:

```
id  select_type  table   type    possible_keys                                                                      key                          key_len  ref                                               rows  Extra                                         

 1  SIMPLE       TCL     const   PRIMARY                                                                            PRIMARY                      4        const                                                1  Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort  
 1  SIMPLE       TCOM    ref     PRIMARY,FK_COMENTARIO_CLASIFICACION,FK_COMENTARIO_EMPRESA,FK_COMENTARIO_CATEGORIA  FK_COMENTARIO_CLASIFICACION  4        const                                               18                                                
 1  SIMPLE       TCA     eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                                            PRIMARY                      4        FACTURACION_WEB_DEV.TCOM.FK_ID_TAREA_CATEGORIA       1                                                
 1  SIMPLE       TE      ALL     PRIMARY                                                                            (NULL)                       (NULL)   (NULL)                                               3  Using where                                   
 1  SIMPLE       T       ref     TIPO,CLIENTE,PETICION                                                              CLIENTE                      768      FACTURACION_WEB_DEV.TCOM.TAREA_CLIENTE              76  Using where
```

That "type ALL" on TE (TAREA_EMPRESA_) is what can't stop bothering me cause it doesn't make sense. I got indexes for every single column (that PRIMARY included), so I don't know why it's not using the index when joining both tables.

This is what I got on TE:

Columns: 
[image: Columns]

Indexes:

[image: Indexes]

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
TAREA_EMPRESA_ contains this:

```
PK_ID_TAREA_EMPRESA  NOMBRE                ORDEN  FECHA_BAJA  

              1  CR ENERGIA                3        (NULL)
              2  SPAIRAL COMMERCE          2        (NULL)
              3  KNET COMUNICACIONES       4        (NULL)
              4  IR SOLUCIONES             1        (NULL)
```

Comment: Does the table `TAREA_EMPRESA` contain a few rows? It also looks like you are misusing a MySQL GROUP BY "feature" https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes, it contains this: (edited the question)

Comment: MySQL planner/optimzer is costs based and calculated that a full scan (one random disk i/o) was faster vs 4 random disk i/o when using indexes.. So don't worry about ALL in this case the optimizer did it right..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for your help, Raymond!

Comment: Other tip if you are using MySQL 5.6+ you can use `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` to get more information also shows you the costs of execution. Also MySQL 5.6+ contains a optimizer trace ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer-tracing.html ) which also gives extra information on why MySQL optimizer did choose a plan.